# can't snap using blender

Tags: snapping

it's really driving me crazy when I followed the tutorial he was making the icing dribbling but it didn't work with me, it was like stretching but the part where I pulled the icing disappears, I can't even describe it, and yes I used snap to face with project individual elements
[image: when I moved the vertex]

in object mode it becomes ugly

[image: view in object mode]

Comment: There may not be anything wrong here. Unless the icing exactly matches the donut in topology, faces will intersect each other. Once you extrude the icing, this will not be much of a problem. The icing probably soaks into the donut in real life anyway.

Comment: As TheLabCat says it's probably normal, if you want to avoid that you need more topology so that you can move the face away